# Xcode UI Test - how to tap() link in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, wkwebview, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to tap a link in a WKWebView using UI Test. The link is defined like so:

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#haloLogin">
<img src=/Images/Halo_small.png">
</a>
```

I'm able to locate the link like this:

```
let haloLink = app.links.elementBoundByIndex(1)
```

(There's another link at index 0)

This is what I get when I print out haloLink.debugDescription:

```
haloLink: Attributes: Link 0x1257094e0: traits: 146029019138, {{143.0, -392.0}, {32.0, 32.0}}

Element subtree:
→Link 0x1257094e0: traits: 146029019138, {{143.0, -392.0}, {32.0, 32.0}}
Image 0x125709cf0: traits: 146029019142, {{143.0, -392.0}, {32.0, 32.0}}
```

I've tried using

```
app.links["#haloLogin"]
```

without success.

My problem is that I'm not getting

```
haloLink.tap()
```

to work.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I now actually got

```
let haloLink = app.links.elementBoundByIndex(1)
haloLink.tap()
```

to work! Probably missed something before.

Answer (score 3):

If the element in wkwebviw like this.

```
<a href="#">your link text</a>
```

Then the test code is below

```
app.links["your link text"].tap()
```

Look more in the article. [UI Testing Cheat Sheet and Examples](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-tap-links-in-a-web-view)

Answer (score 2):

Access the link via the contained image. In your question your image's filename is `Halo_small.png`, so you can `tap()` it with:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.images["Halo_small.png"].tap()
```

Comment: I just tried it but it still doesn't recognize it :(

Comment: @Joe Masilotti - I ran into an issue where the </a> tag does not have any text or attributes. For example this is what I am trying to find and tap using UI Test: <a><div id="facebook"></div></a>. Is there a way to find the div id?

Answer (score 0):

In a UITextView with an attributed text link this worked for me:

```
XCUIApplication().links["your link text"].press(forDuration: 0.1)
```

`tap()` did not trigger the link.